# How to Ensure Footnote Width Expansion in Two Side-by-Side Tabulars Spanning the Full Page Width (with table*) of a Two-Column Document?

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularx, two-column, threeparttable

The `footnote` within my table appears constrained to the width of the first tabular section, and I'm seeking a way to extend it to occupy the entire width of the table.

My document is formatted in `two-column` style, and I've employed the `table*` environment to expand the table across the entire page width. Within this structure, I've arranged two tabular sections side by side to form two distinct tables. Additionally, I'm utilizing the `threeparttable` package to incorporate table notes.

The provided code generates the output in the figure below. I want to enhance the footnote to encompass all the white space highlighted in red.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text; you can remove this in your actual document

\usepackage{geometry} %margins of the document
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\usepackage{showframe} % to show page margins

\title{two_colums_two_columns}
\author{alexyshr }
\date{January 2024}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]


\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-5pt} %reduce default column separation

\begin{table*}[hbt!] %table* will expand the table to all the space available
\caption{SOF Metrics. All providers. Florida Power Grid - PG}

\centering
\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{}clcccccc}
\toprule
  & \textbf{County} & \textbf{\makecell[c]{SOF\\MERS$^\dagger$}} & \textbf{\makecell[c]{SOF\\MERA$^\ast$}} & \textbf{$\beta_0^\ddagger$} & \textbf{$\beta_1^\S$} & \textbf{$\#^\P$} & \vphantom{1} \textbf{\makecell[c]{Risk\\Ratio}}\\
\midrule
\em{1} & OSCEOLA & 46.0 & 0.511 & -7.176 & 0.156 & 10 & 0.720\\
\em{2} & HILLSBOROUGH & 45.0 & 0.500 & -7.003 & 0.156 & 10 & 0.736\\
\em{3} & SUMTER & 44.7 & 0.497 & -8.823 & 0.197 & 10 & 0.740\\
\em{4} & PALM BEACH & 43.9 & 0.488 & -10.656 & 0.243 & 10 & 0.754\\
\em{5} & MIAMI-DADE & 43.6 & 0.484 & -9.377 & 0.215 & 10 & 0.760\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para]
\item[$\ast$] \text{$\equiv$ SOF-MERS: Multi-Event median Robustness wind Speed; }
\item[$\dagger$] \text{$\equiv$ SOF-MERA: Multi-Event Robustness Area.}
\item[$\ddagger$] \text{$\equiv$ Intercept; }
\item[$\S$] \text{$\equiv$ Slope; }
\item[$\P$] \text{$\equiv$ Number of Hurricane Events.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{clcccccc}
\toprule
\em{ } & \textbf{County} & \textbf{\makecell[c]{SOF\\MERS$^\dagger$}} & \textbf{\makecell[c]{SOF\\MERA$^\ast$}} & \textbf{$\beta_0^\ddagger$} & \textbf{$\beta_1^\S$} & \textbf{$\#^\P$} & \textbf{\makecell[c]{Risk\\Ratio}}\\
\midrule
\em{35} & HAMILTON & 32.3 & 0.359 & -7.244 & 0.224 & 10 & 1.024\\
\em{36} & DIXIE & 32.2 & 0.358 & -10.633 & 0.330 & 10 & 1.027\\
\em{37} & PUTNAM & 32.2 & 0.357 & -9.266 & 0.288 & 10 & 1.030\\
\em{38} & FLAGLER & 32.0 & 0.356 & -9.695 & 0.303 & 10 & 1.033\\
\em{\cellcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{$>>$}}} & \cellcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{ALL}} & \cellcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{33.1}} & \cellcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{0.368}} & \cellcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{-7.776}} & \cellcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{0.235}} & \cellcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{683}} & \cellcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{1.000}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[3-15]

%return to normal column separation
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{1pt} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you encase both of the smaller `tabular` environment in an "outer" two-column `tabular` environment and let the "outer" tabular env. span the full width of the textblock. Then, make sure that `threeparttable` environment encases this "outer" tabular env.

I would also load the `siunitx` package and use its `S` column type for the `$\beta_0$` columns in both inner `tabular` environments, both to align the numbers on their decimal markers and to get proper math-minus signs.

By the way, there's no need to **bold-face** the cells in the header rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text; you can remove this in your actual document

\usepackage{geometry} %margins of the document
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, margin=20mm}

\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type


%\usepackage{showframe} % to show page margins


\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table*}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default: 6pt
\footnotesize

\caption{SOF Metrics. All providers. Florida Power Grid -- PG}

\smallskip
\begin{threeparttable}

% "outer" table
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
 
% first "inner" table
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\em}l l cc S[table-format=-1.3] ccc @{}}
\toprule
  & County 
  & \makecell{SOF\\MERS\tnote{\textdagger}} 
  & \makecell{SOF\\MERA\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}} 
  & {$\beta_0$\tnote{$\ddagger$}}
  & $\beta_1$\tnote{\S} 
  & \#\tnote{\P}
  & \makecell{Risk\\Ratio}\\
\midrule
1 & OSCEOLA      & 46.0 & 0.511 &  -7.176 & 0.156 & 10 & 0.720\\
2 & HILLSBOROUGH & 45.0 & 0.500 &  -7.003 & 0.156 & 10 & 0.736\\
3 & SUMTER       & 44.7 & 0.497 &  -8.823 & 0.197 & 10 & 0.740\\
4 & PALM BEACH.  & 43.9 & 0.488 & -10.656 & 0.243 & 10 & 0.754\\
5 & MIAMI-DADE   & 43.6 & 0.484 &  -9.377 & 0.215 & 10 & 0.760\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} % end of first "inner" table
\hspace{5pt}
% second "inner" table
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{2pt}} >{\em}l l cc S[table-format=-1.3] ccc @{\hspace{2pt}}} 
\toprule
  & County 
  & \makecell{SOF\\MERS\tnote{\textdagger}} 
  & \makecell{SOF\\MERA\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}} 
  & {$\beta_0$\tnote{$\ddagger$}}
  & $\beta_1$\tnote{\S}
  & \#\tnote{\P}
  & \makecell{Risk\\Ratio}\\
\midrule
35 & HAMILTON & 32.3 & 0.359 &  -7.244 & 0.224 &  10 & 1.024\\
36 & DIXIE    & 32.2 & 0.358 & -10.633 & 0.330 &  10 & 1.027\\
37 & PUTNAM   & 32.2 & 0.357 &  -9.266 & 0.288 &  10 & 1.030\\
38 & FLAGLER  & 32.0 & 0.356 &  -9.695 & 0.303 &  10 & 1.033\\
\rowcolor{light-gray}
 & ALL               & 33.1 & 0.368 &  -7.776 & 0.235 & 683 & 1.000\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\null
\end{tabular} % end of "outer" tabular

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[\textdagger] SOF-MERS: Multi-Event median Robustness wind Speed; 
\item[\textasteriskcentered] SOF-MERA: Multi-Event Robustness Area;
\item[$\ddagger$] Intercept;
\item[\S] Slope; 
\item[\P] Number of Hurricane Events.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table*}

\lipsum[3-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico, very useful. You changed different useful details. You said "... let the 'outer' tabular env. span the full width of the textblock", but if I change the `\footnotesize` to `\scriptsize` then the table is not using all the page width available.  How can I ensure the table uses all the page width available?

Comment: @alexyshr - Not rendering some of the header cells and the final row of the second `tabular` env. in **bold** and deleting `$>>$` made it possible for me to switch from `\scriptsize` to `\footnotesize`, while still allowing for a useful value of `\tabcolsep`. Why would you want to revert to `scriptsize`? However, if for whatever reason you insist on reverting to `\scriptsize`, just increase the value of `\tabcolsep` suitably to make the tables once more span the full width of the textblock.

Comment: The real table in my paper (another table) does not use all the page widths available. I thought that maybe any special command would automatically expand the table without consideration of the font size. I will fix it by hand using `\tabcolsep` and `\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont` or any specific command to change font size.

Comment: @alexyshr - If the main document font size is `{10}{12}`, i.e., the default for plain-TeX and LaTeX documents, then `\footnotesize` is exactly equivalent to `{8}{10}`. A deeper reason for why there's no easy way to set an overall target width is because the `threeparttable` machinery is getting in the way.